# Third-party screensavers only filling 1/4 screen since Catalina?

Tags: catalina, screensaver

I use third-party screensavers, especially a snow-themed one around the holidays. However, some of them only take up the bottom-left quarter of the screen now.

[image: Desktop & Screen Saver Preference Pane showing screensaver preview filling only bottom-left quarter of black preview window]

The screensaver preview is exactly how it shows up when activated. This doesn't hold for all of my screensavers. Some of them don't work at all and just show a black screen, and a couple work just fine. Doesn't seem to be any correlation with which developer they came from. I've run all updates, removed/reinstalled the screensaver, and tried adjusting scaling in the Displays preferences to no avail.

Comment: If the stock screensavers work correctly and some of the 3rd-party work correctly, the problem is probably from the developers of the non-working screensavers.  Have you contact them about this problem?